# Spring Project Reactor for Kinesis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, amazon-kinesis, reactive-streams

I have a micro service that consumes data from Kinesis stream , I want to convert it into reactive stream consumer since application is already written using spring-boot 2.x. I was going through support of Project Rector for Kinesis and found few example like [aws sdk example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/kinesis/src/main/java/com/example/kinesis/KinesisStreamReactorEx.java).
I want to know if there is better way to do this. There are dedicated projects for streaming with Kafka and project reactor , is there any such thing for Kinesis ?